# Where do I require the songkickr gem file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rubygems

I am attempting to use the songkickr gem in a rails app. I have installed the gem using the

```
gem install songkickr
```

The next step of the instruction is to:

```
require 'songkickr'
remote = Songkickr::Remote.new API_KEY
```

Where do I do this? In what file?

The github page for the gem is https://github.com/jrmehle/songkickr
and my github for this is on https://github.com/jeremybelcher/travel

Sorry for the beginner question, trying to lean al this. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your gemfile at your application root you need to add the line

```
gem 'songkickr'
```

Then run

```
bundle
```

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have actually already done that. This comes up when I run the bundle command, so its in there.                                              
Using songkickr (0.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

Add `require 'songkickr'` to your application controller

Example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery
  require 'songkickr'
end
```

Comment: Thanks ahmet. I tried that and it just crashed. i got the error LoadError in PagesController#newyork

cannot load such file -- songkickr
Rails.root: /Users/Jeremy/code/travel

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   songkickr
Request

Parameters:

None
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None

Answer (score 0):

There are several places where you can put ruby code in a Ruby on Rails app and you should just choose one of them, depending which makes the most sense for you application.  For a start, how about you just try putting that code in one of your controllers?

In your Gemfile, add:

```
gem 'songkickr'
```

Then run the following command: `bundle`

At the top of the controller put:

```
require 'songkickr'
API_KEY = ""  # edit this line
```

Then in some action you can do this to test it out:

```
remote = Songkickr::Remote.new API_KEY
```

Later you might decide to make the "remote" object persist between requests and then you would need to do something more complicated.